# OpenSSL.NET can't export private key with null Cipher

Tags: .net, openssl, private-key

I've recently discovered [OpenSSL.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openssl-net/) and it's a pretty sweet little wrapper.

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
    public static void DoSomething(byte[] buf)
    {
        OpenSSL.Core.BIO input = new OpenSSL.Core.BIO(buf);
        OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate b = OpenSSL.X509.X509Certificate.FromPKCS12(input, "passphrase");
        OpenSSL.Core.BIO outs = OpenSSL.Core.BIO.MemoryBuffer(false);
        b.PrivateKey.WritePrivateKey(outs, OpenSSL.Crypto.Cipher.Null, "passphrase");
        outs.SetClose(OpenSSL.Core.BIO.CloseOption.Close);
        Console.WriteLine(outs.ReadString());
    }
```

Problem comes at the "b.PrivateKey.WritePrivateKey(.." line.  I want to write the private key out without any encryption.  According to spec, if I use a Null cipher type this should do the trick, but it never works, regardless of the cert I use in buf.

Here's the exception:

error:0D0A706C:asn1 encoding routines:PKCS5_pbe2_set:cipher has no object identifier
error:2307D00D:PKCS12 routines:PKCS8_encrypt:ASN1 lib

I know this part works fine because if I specify any other cipher type, it exports the private key without fail.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you use:

```
    OpenSSL.Core.BIO outs = OpenSSL.Core.BIO.MemoryBuffer(false);
    outs.Write(b.PrivateKey.ToString());
    outs.SetClose(OpenSSL.Core.BIO.CloseOption.Close);
    Console.WriteLine(outs.ReadString());
```

this way you can write unencrypted keys.

I see, change that to:

```
    OpenSSL.Core.BIO outs = OpenSSL.Core.BIO.MemoryBuffer(false);
    outs.Write(b.PrivateKey.GetRSA().PrivateKeyAsPEM);
    outs.SetClose(OpenSSL.Core.BIO.CloseOption.Close);
    Console.WriteLine(outs.ReadString());
```

Comment: PrivateKey.ToString() creates an ascii (human readable) representation of the private key.  True all of the data is present, but I'm looking to get the RAW/Unencrypted binary private key data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really use that but perhaps this may help:

> If OpenSSL is being compiled for a
>   development system in which SSL will
>   be debugged at the protocol level,
>   omitting the command
>   -DSSL_FORBID_ENULLis acceptable. -DSSL_FORBID_ENULL causes OpenSSL to omit null ciphers in the SSL cipher
>   suite. Null ciphers permit cleartext
>   (unencrypted information) to traverse
>   the wire. Null ciphers provide no
>   confidentiality and aren't encouraged
>   for use on production systems.